# Multiple SPF Record Format Validation Not Working

Tags: dns

I am trying to validate multiple SPF record but it is not validating.

```
v=spf1 include:mailgun.org  +a +mx include:marketheroSPF.smtp.com ?all
```

I tested it with mxtoolbox and it gives me passed status

```
v   version spf1        The SPF record version
+   include mailgun.org Pass    The specified domain is searched for an 'allow'.
+   a       Pass    Match if IP has a DNS 'A' record in given domain
+   mx      Pass    Match if IP is one of the MX hosts for given domain name
+   include marketheroSPF.smtp.com  Pass    The specified domain is searched for an 'allow'.
?   all     Neutral Always matches. It goes at the end of your record.
```

However the platform told me that my SPF record is not valid so I am wondering if my **TXT** record is in wrong format or they platform just does not know how to read multiple SPF format.

Comment: It looks okay to me. If you share the `domain name` and the output of `the platform` that told you your SPF is not valid we might be able to see why.

Comment: Thanks I do not own the domain so I cannot share it however the platform is called MarketHero.  The MailGun is fine reading the multiple SPF and I also validated it using https://www.kitterman.com/spf/ but MarketHero is insisting that my SPF record is not correct and that I also need the SPF record to connect the domain to there platform which surprises me as from I know, you do not need SPF record to connect to a domain. Anyway I have given up on them or given up connecting the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [official syntax guideline](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax), try this one out.

```
v=spf1 a mx include:mailgun.org include:marketheroSPF.smtp.com ?all
```

The order matters and maybe the included records are malformed (expecially the second one). If this linked record have a leading `0`, this could be one of the issues.
Depending on the parser the `+` in front of `a` and `mx` may cause errors since the default qualifier is already "+", i.e. "Pass".

Otherwise please provide more details. Hope that helps :)